# Why does regex with \\$\{ work with egrep, but not with sed?

Tags: sed, grep, regular-expression, quoting

Given a text like this

```
./RFF_09 -f${FILE} -c${COND}
```

inside a file, this egrep command will correctly match:

```
egrep './RFF(.*) (.*)-c\\$\{COND\}' file
```

but this sed command will not

```
sed -n "s:'./RFF(.*) (.*)-c\\$\{COND\}':./RFF$1 $2-cRFF$1:gp"
```

It will fail with `sed: -e expression #1, char 38: invalid content of \{\}`.
I've also tried with

```
sed -n "s:'./RFF(.*) (.*)-c\\$\{COND\}':DUMMY:gp" file
sed -n s:'./RFF(.*) (.*)-c\\$\{COND\}':DUMMY:gp file
```

with the same result.

```
sed -n "s:'./RFF(.*) (.*)-c\\$\\{COND\\}':DUMMY:gp" file
```

Will not give me an error message, but will not match.

What am I doing wrong? Or better: How can I replace the text as suggested by the original command? I'm using rather old versions of sed (4.1.2) and egrep (2.5.1), so a workaround is appreciated even if you can't reproduce the error with newer versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use **e**grep that mean grep with extended regexp syntax so to be able to transfer your pattern into sed you have to add parametr `-r(--regexp-extended)` or `-E` in some versions.

Regarding to your expression you have extra `\` after `c` so even with egrep it **does not match**

Additionally your better use `\1` instead `$1` for reverse-matching.

So final command could be:

```
sed -rn 's:\./(RFF.*)( .* -c)\$\{COND\}:./\1\2\1:gp'
```

Or

```
sed -rn 's:(\./(RFF\S*) \S* -c)\$\{COND\}:\1\2:gp'
```

Comment: Great, this works. Yes, the extra \ is a typo, it was from when the expression had no '' to double-escape the $ from both bash and regex.

Comment: @Chaos_99 Just single qoute (`'`) have escape effect. Double-quote expand variables (which usually been marked by `$`) instead.

Answer (score 2):

In your original statement the problem is that you're mixing syntactic and literal [quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes): the single quotes within the double quotes will be matched literally. You'll want to either simply remove them or mix quotes (*not* nest them). Untested examples:

```
sed 's/foo/{bar}/'
sed "s/foo/"'{bar}'"/"
```

There are many [flavours of regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines), and they all support different syntax.  In the attempt using only single quotes the issue is the regex flavour: `sed` uses `\{N\}` for match counts, so `N` needs to be an integer. You'll want to instead use `{COND}`.

(Truly, using a regex to solve a problem now means you have *two* problems. And doing pretty much anything complex in shell code means you have N problems, N being at least as large as the number of lines.)

Comment: Only using `""` or `''` on the outside as well as switching the quotes `'""'` instead of `"''"` still gives my the `invalid content` message. Using no quotes will break at `unexpected token near '('` (probably the blank space). How do I quote this correctly?

Comment: Please read the linked article about quoting.

Comment: I did read the linked article. It did not help me. Single quotes should solve my problem, but they don't. Probably because this will be evaluated more than once. Double single-quotes didn't help either. I would be thankful for an example.

Comment: What do you mean it "will be evaluated more than once"? And **I never even mentioned double single quotes.**